# How to convert large number string into integers in jsr223 sampler with groovy

Tags: testing, jmeter, jsr223

I am using a jsr223 sampler to read jtl file and break it into multiple files, cant use csv data set configure for some reason. I am using groovy as language

```js
def INPUT_FILE = vars.get("INPUT_FILE");
def lines = new File(INPUT_FILE).readLines();
int start = lines[1].split(',')[0].toInteger(); //taking second line first column and converting to int
log.info("=====read start: " + start); //displaying in logs
```

This is giving error, unable to figure out the fix, tried out with long, def data types

[image]

Comment: You can't,why you need integer? You can log it as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is too large to be an Integer, the [maximum value for the 32-bit Integer is 2,147,483,647](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). Consider using [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) class instead

```
def INPUT_FILE = vars.get("INPUT_FILE");
def lines = new File(INPUT_FILE).readLines();
long start = lines[1].split(',')[0].toLong(); //taking second line first column and converting to int
log.info("=====read start: " + start); //displaying in logs
```

---

Also be aware that if you just want to read the value from the CSV file and print it to *jmeter.log* you don't even need the scripting, you can go for [__CSVRead()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) and [__log()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) functions instead.